# Combine "person" table, "logged on" table and "data" table to get person with latest logged on date that has data

Tags: sql, join, timestamp, greatest-n-per-group

I have three tables:

```
Table 1: PERSON  
  personName varchar2 unique 
  personGender varchar2 
  personAge int

Table 2: LOGGED_ON_LOG  
  id int unique  
  personName varchar2  
  loggedOn timestamp  

Table 3: DATA  
  id int unique  
  personName varchar2  
  dataContent varchar2
```

I have been trying to write a join statement to retrieve a result of all persons that has data in DATA table with the last time they logged in.
I know I can do:

```
SELECT loggedOn FROM LOGGED_ON_LOG WHERE loggedOn IN (SELECT max(loggedOn)     as loggedOn FROM LOGGED_ON_LOG WHERE personName='John Doe');
```

to get the last time a user was logged on.

And I can do:

```
SELECT personName, personGender, personAge FROM PERSON WHERE personName IN (SELECT DISTINCT personName FROM DATA);
```

to get all persons that have data.

How can I join these two selects so that I get a result of:
personName, personGender, personAge, loggedOn

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Embedded Apache Derby

Comment: Not related to your question, but having a unique constraint on the person's name could lead to problems.  Also, age changes over time so storing that might not be the best idea either.

Comment: This is really just a simplified version of my schema.  I am actually storing the person's birth date, but I am making  username aka unique.  I know not the best design but it suits what I need it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not getting a response because not that many folks have used apache derby but this should work for most dbmses if not necessarily optimized:

```
SELECT p.personName, p.personGender, p.personAge, Max( loggedOn)
  FROM PERSON p, Logged_on_log l
 WHERE p.personName = l.personName
   AND exists (SELECT 1 FROM DATA d where d.person_name = p.person_name)
GROUP BY p.personName, p.personGender, p.personAge
```

If for some reason derby doesn't support group bys you could just add your subquery:

```
 AND loggedOn = (
  SELECT max(loggedOn) FROM LOGGED_ON_LOG l2 
  WHERE p.personName = l2.person_name)
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks!  I did change Max(loggedOn) to Max(l.loggedOn), not sure if that makes a difference or not.